# Where's the "vote to close" button?

Tags: discussion, support, closing-questions

I was considering voting to close [I'm creating an original setting for D&D--where do I start?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/im-creating-an-original-setting-for-dd-where-do-i-start) as a duplicate but there is no 'close' button.

Vote to close takes 250 rep (which I have)

Is it 'cause it's a considerable upvoted question?

Given the activity on that question I think it would be wise to merge it with [What qualities are important when creating a fantasy RPG campaign?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-qualities-are-important-when-creating-a-fantasy-rpg-campaign)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote to close your own question is 250, vote to close someone else's question is 3000 rep.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh